# Realm Object Server: "The client is unsupported"

Tags: java, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server, realm-java

I'm using the Realm Object Server on latest Beta, version 2.0.0-rc2-285.

When I'm trying to populate the realm with Java client version 3.7.0, I'm getting the following error on the server:

"The client is unsupported"

Which version of the Java client is compatible with Realm Object Server beta?

Comment: The latest java release for ROS 2.0 is `4.0.0-BETA2-afe7114-SNAPSHOT` See https://github.com/realm/realm-java#using-snapshots about how to use snapshot release.

Comment: @beeender thanks now it works! Do you know where I find the correct beta version for the realm-js library too? Same problem there..

Comment: Figured it out, it's version `2.0.0-rc5`.